# Can I ask a questions about the Microsoft interview process on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, site-recommendation

The gist of the question I want to ask is the following:

> I am preparing for an interview for Account Technology Strategist at Microsoft in NY. I have very few details about this position. I wanted to know more about the interview process and the nature of the interview. Please share any information that you think is relevant to this context.

Would such a question be appropriate for Stack Overflow, or is there an other site within the SE network where it would be on-topic?

Comment: Big no. It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Oh, and even if there were another site on the network in which it was on topic, it's way too broad.  "Tell me everything about the interview process." is way too much info for an SE answer to be able to contain.

Comment: I'm glad you asked here before posting :) It's not a suitable question for any Stack Exchange site due to being so broad and open-ended, however if you have the rep for it you could try checking out one of the chat rooms. The [Workplace chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), [Programmers chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), or one of the [SO chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) come to mind.

Comment: In addition to the fact that there's no way to know an answer is correct. What happens at one interview might not happen at another.. and as years pass those questions/processes *will* change negating older "correct" answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow is for programming questions - questions about an interview process are most certainly not programming questions. So, the answer to that is no.

However, if you can generalize the question enough so it is not specific to Microsoft and yourself, you can look at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange beta site (though you should read the FAQ and follow it there before posting).

Do note, that in general, we expect questions to be specific and answerable (that is, have an answer that can be objectively correct).

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question for workplace here.  There's nothing specific.  "Tell me about what interviews are like" is the non-company specific adaptation, and that's way, way too broad for a workplace question.

Comment: @Servy For once I *almost* agreed with you that there's no way to ask that question on SE, but upon further inspection it could possibly be suitable if it focused specifically on what to expect from the interview process for a programming position with a large company like MS, and guided answers towards a good canonical answer outlining the generic interview process, instead of multiple answers each containing one piece of the answer.

Comment: @Rachel I'm not active on workplace, so it would need to be discussed at their meta, but that still seems way, way too broad of a question.  It seems like it would be an entire tag/category of questions for them.

Comment: @Servy FWIW, [Rachel](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/316/rachel "WP user profile") and [Oded](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/1513/oded "WP user profile") are quite active Workplace users

Comment: @Servy Yeah, it's definitely the sort of question I'd want to bring up in chat or on meta to get it going in the right direction. I've participated in the Workplace and in their chat a bit, and it seems like the sort of OK question they'd want provided it gets guided towards a single answer outlining the generic process that you can expect, and it doesn't result in a lot of answers each saying *"you also might experience X"*

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response. I have some specific questions too. I will check out the 'workplace' forum before I post it.

Comment: @scr it's not a forum...